# Why when i create the bitmap it's empty all white?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private Bitmap CropImage()
        {
            Bitmap pic = pictureBoxSnap.Image as Bitmap;
            Bitmap cropped = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(cropped))
            {
                g.DrawImage(pic, new Rectangle(0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height),
                             rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            pic.Save(@"c:\temp\testingitimage.jpg");
            cropped.Save(@"c:\temp\testingitimage1.bmp");
            return cropped;

        }
```

I added this two lines of Save to test what i get. The first one pic i see the correct image that is in the pictureBox.
But the second one cropped is all white and empty.

And i call this method from the pictureBox paint event:

```
private void pictureBoxSnap_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            if (pictureBoxSnap.Image != null)
            {
                {
                    if (ClearGraphics == false)
                    {
                        if (cropRect == false)
                        {
                            if (rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] != Rectangle.Empty)
                            {
                                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex]);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (rect.Width > 10 && rect.Height > 10)
                            {
                                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, rect);
                                pictureBoxSnap.Image = CropImage();
                                Image img = CropImage();
                                img.Save(@"c:\temp\testimageing.jpg");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
```

I used a breakpoint on the: e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, rect); and rect is not empty ( rect is Rectangle i draw on the pictureBox then when i click on a button it's making validate for the pictureBox).

I also did a save here too and testimageing i see it black on the hard disk but when i edit it with Paint i see it's white empty.

For exmaple when i draw a rectangle on the pictureBox then i use a breakpoint in the CropImage method i see that the variable rect is for example: X = 136 Y = 149 Width = 131 Height = 106
Also in the paint event this rect variable have the same values.

And the pictureBox size is: 640x480
And the pictureBox property SizeMode is set to: zoom

Wo why i get empty white image ? And not the cropped rectangle with the part of the image inside ?

EDIT:

This is the code im using now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using DannyGeneral;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MinimizeCapture
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Boolean bHaveMouse;
        Point ptOriginal = new Point();
        Point ptLast = new Point();
        bool cropRect;
        Bitmap cloneBitmap;
        Rectangle recttest;
        private Rectangle Rect;
        private Rectangle[] rectangles;
        private Rectangle RectClone;
        private bool btn = false;
        private Point RectStartPoint = Point.Empty;
        private Point RectEndPoint = Point.Empty;
        private Brush selectionBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        private Pen pen;
        private string selectedIndex;
        private List<string> drawnItems = new List<string>();
        private bool ClearGraphics;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            cropRect = false;
            var windows = OpenWindowGetter.FindWindowsWithText();
            ClearGraphics = false;
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            btn = false;
            pen = new Pen(selectionBrush);
            buttonSnap.Enabled = false;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void buttonSnap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearGraphics = true;
            this.listBoxSnap.Items.Clear();
            this.pictureBoxSnap.Image = null;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void listBoxSnap_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            WindowSnap snap = this.listBoxSnap.SelectedItem as WindowSnap;
            selectedIndex = this.listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex.ToString();
            this.pictureBoxSnap.Image = snap.Image;
            for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.Length; i++)
            {
                if (rectangles[i] != RectClone)
                {
                    ClearGraphics = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    ClearGraphics = true;
                }
            }

        }

        private void checkBoxForceMDI_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowSnap.ForceMDICapturing = (sender as CheckBox).Checked;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            listBoxSnap.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.listBoxSnap.Items.Add("Minimized Windows"); }));
            listBoxSnap.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.listBoxSnap.Items.AddRange(WindowSnap.GetAllWindows(true,true).ToArray()); }));
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            rectangles = new Rectangle[listBoxSnap.Items.Count];
            buttonSnap.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void pictureBoxSnap_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

            if (pictureBoxSnap.Image != null)
            {
                {
                    if (ClearGraphics == false)
                    {

                            if (rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex] != Rectangle.Empty)
                            {
                                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Firebrick, rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex]);
                            }




                    }
                    if (cropRect == true)
                    {
                        if (recttest.Width > 10 && recttest.Height > 10)
                        {
                            //e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gray, recttest);
                            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
                            /*pictureBoxSnap.Image = CropImage();
                            Image img = CropImage();
                            img.Save(@"c:\temp\testimageing.jpg");*/

                        }
                    }
                }
            }           
        }

        private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (btn == true)
            {
                ClearGraphics = false;
                RectEndPoint = e.Location;
                int currentindex = listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex;
                rectangles[currentindex] = RectClone;
                Rect = getRect(RectStartPoint, RectEndPoint);
                RectClone = Rect;
                pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
            }

            Point ptCurrent = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        // If we "have the mouse", then we draw our lines.
            if (bHaveMouse)
            {
                // If we have drawn previously, draw again in
                // that spot to remove the lines.
                if (ptLast.X != -1)
                {
                    MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ptOriginal, ptLast);
                }
                // Update last point.
                ptLast = ptCurrent;
                // Draw new lines.
                MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ptOriginal, ptCurrent);
            }
        }

        private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            RectStartPoint = e.Location;
            btn = true;
            Rect = Rectangle.Empty;
            RectClone = Rectangle.Empty;

            bHaveMouse = true;
            // Store the "starting point" for this rubber-band rectangle.
            ptOriginal.X = e.X;
            ptOriginal.Y = e.Y;
            // Special value lets us know that no previous
            // rectangle needs to be erased.
            ptLast.X = -1;
            ptLast.Y = -1;
        }

        private void pictureBoxSnap_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            recttest = rectangles[listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex];
            ClearGraphics = false;
            btn = false;
            RectEndPoint = e.Location;
            pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
            int currentindex = listBoxSnap.SelectedIndex;
            rectangles[currentindex] = RectClone;

            // Set internal flag to know we no longer "have the mouse".
            bHaveMouse = false;
            // If we have drawn previously, draw again in that spot
            // to remove the lines.
            if (ptLast.X != -1)
            {
                Point ptCurrent = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
                MyDrawReversibleRectangle(ptOriginal, ptLast);
            }
            // Set flags to know that there is no "previous" line to reverse.
            ptLast.X = -1;
            ptLast.Y = -1;
            ptOriginal.X = -1;
            ptOriginal.Y = -1;
            pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
        }

        Rectangle getRect(Point p1, Point p2)
        {
            Point p = new Point(Math.Min(p1.X, p2.X), Math.Min(p1.Y, p2.Y));
            Size s = new Size(Math.Abs(p1.X - p2.X), Math.Abs(p1.Y - p2.Y));
            return new Rectangle(p, s);
        }

        private void ConfirmRectangle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConfirmRectangle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = false;
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\Settings.txt", true);
            w.WriteLine("Rectangle Location: " + RectClone.Location + " Rectangle Size: " + RectClone.Size + " Selected Index: " + selectedIndex);
            textBoxIndex.Text = selectedIndex.ToString();
            w.Close();
            cropRect = false;
            //pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
            Image img = CropImage();
            img.Save(@"c:\temp\testimageing.jpg");
            pictureBoxSnap.Image = img;

        }

        // Convert and normalize the points and draw the reversible frame.
        private void MyDrawReversibleRectangle(Point p1, Point p2)
        {
            Rectangle rc = new Rectangle();
            // Convert the points to screen coordinates.
            p1 = pictureBoxSnap.PointToScreen(p1);
            p2 = pictureBoxSnap.PointToScreen(p2);
            // Normalize the rectangle.
            if (p1.X < p2.X)
            {
                rc.X = p1.X;
                rc.Width = p2.X - p1.X;
            }
            else
            {
                rc.X = p2.X;
                rc.Width = p1.X - p2.X;
            }
            if (p1.Y < p2.Y)
            {
                rc.Y = p1.Y;
                rc.Height = p2.Y - p1.Y;
            }
            else
            {
                rc.Y = p2.Y;
                rc.Height = p1.Y - p2.Y;
            }
            // Draw the reversible frame.
            rect = new Rectangle(pictureBoxSnap.PointToClient(rc.Location), rc.Size);
            ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame(rc, Color.Gray, FrameStyle.Dashed);
        }

        Rectangle rect = Rectangle.Empty;

        private Bitmap CropImage()
        {
            //rect = recttest;
            Bitmap pic = pictureBoxSnap.Image as Bitmap;
            Bitmap cropped = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(cropped))
            {
                g.DrawImage(pic, new Rectangle(0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height),
                             rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            pic.Save(@"c:\temp\testingitimage.jpg");
            cropped.Save(@"c:\temp\testingitimage1.bmp");
            return cropped;

        }
    }
}
```

Moved the CropImage call method from the paint and added it to the button click here:

```
private void ConfirmRectangle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConfirmRectangle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            ConfirmRectangle.Enabled = false;
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\Settings.txt", true);
            w.WriteLine("Rectangle Location: " + RectClone.Location + " Rectangle Size: " + RectClone.Size + " Selected Index: " + selectedIndex);
            textBoxIndex.Text = selectedIndex.ToString();
            w.Close();
            cropRect = false;
            //pictureBoxSnap.Invalidate();
            Image img = CropImage();
            img.Save(@"c:\temp\testimageing.jpg");
            pictureBoxSnap.Image = img;

        }
```

This lines:

```
Image img = CropImage();
img.Save(@"c:\temp\testimageing.jpg");
pictureBoxSnap.Image = img;
```

But what i get in the pictureBox is this:

[image: eZoom in ?]

Not sure why. The rectangle is in the position i drawed it's ok but instead showing the part of the original image cut in the rectangle it's doing like zoom in.

Comment: Don't call `CropImage()` inside the paint event.

Comment: valter ok i moved it out from the paint and i call it now through a button click. But what i get now is the image in the pictureBox gto very large from inside like zoom in and not the part i marked with the rectangle.

Comment: valter updated my question with the code now and what i get. If you could take a look please. Thanks.

Comment: So you want the original image in picturebox plus the rectangle with part of it? Why do you use zoom, in picture box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Bitmap CropImage(){
    Bitmap pic = pictureBoxSnap.Image as Bitmap;
    Bitmap cropped = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(cropped)){
        g.DrawImage(pic, new Rectangle(0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height),
                         rect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    }

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pic)){
        g.DrawImage(cropped , 136, 149, rect.Width, rect.Height);
        //Draw the rectangle
    }

    //pic.Save(@"c:\temp\testingitimage.jpg");
    //cropped.Save(@"c:\temp\testingitimage1.bmp");
    return pic;
}
```

valter

Answer (score 1):

You are cropping multiple times.

```
pictureBoxSnap.Image = CropImage();    // First Time
Image img = CropImage();               // Second Time
img.Save(@"c:\temp\testimageing.jpg");
```

You just need to crop once. Here you are using same picturebox for source and for cropped image. first time when you crop then image. the cropped image will be set correctly to the picturebox. but, second time application will try to crop that image again.

You should do like this

```
Image img = CropImage();    
img.Save(@"c:\temp\testimageing.jpg");
pictureBoxSnap.Image = img;
```

Comment: Changed it but still i get empty rectangle gray for a milisecond i see some image in very big zoom in the pictureBox and it's gone.

Comment: Shell i added to my question my code as im using it now. Changed as you said in the paint so it will call the CropImage method once. And still  i get empty gray rectangle.